# Python 3: list index issue

Tags: python

I've been coding in python 2.7 up until now and trying to use python 3

I am facing an issue with appending to a list that I don't understand, and is puzzling to me

```
with open('path/AuthorNames.csv' ,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader) ## this generates [[auther1],[auther2],...]
    l2 = []
    for item in your_list:
        l2.append(item[0])
```

running this results in IndexError: list index out of range

Why? I have an empty list, I am appending items from my for loop into that list, I am not changing the existing list.

is there a new approach to lists in python3?

example of for item in your_list: print item

```
['\ufeffArticle Author']
['Thomas B. Bennettd1 Barry Friedmandd1 Andrew D. Martinddd1 Susan Navarro Smelcer']
['Thomas B. Bennettd1 Barry Friedmandd1 Andrew D. Martinddd1 Susan Navarro Smelcer']
['Thomas B. Bennettd1 Barry Friedmandd1 Andrew D. Martinddd1 Susan Navarro Smelcer']
['Thomas B. Bennettd1 Barry Friedmandd1 Andrew D. Martinddd1 Susan Navarro Smelcer']
['Thomas B. Bennettd1 Barry Friedmandd1 Andrew D. Martinddd1 Susan Navarro Smelcer']
['Thomas B. Bennettd1 Barry Friedmandd1 Andrew D. Martinddd1 Susan Navarro Smelcer']
```

Comment: y = [['aa'],['ab']]; l = []; for i in y:
...   l.append(i[0]) works correctly for me in 3.7. Are you sure of what your_list contains? auther1 in "", right?

Comment: a print of the two first items added to the post

Comment: If the items are nonempty lists, `l2.append(item[0])` is unproblematic in Python 3. There is something in `your_list` which you are not perceiving correctly. Does `min(len(item) for item in your_list)` return `0`?

Comment: yes returns 0 from min

Comment: there may empty line in CSV file

Comment: There is an empty list in there then (as the error itself makes almost certain). In any event, why not just skip the loop and use `l2 = [item[0] for item in your_list if len(item) > 0]`?

Comment: with the min == 0, there definitely is. Like at the last line?

Comment: @JohnColeman The condition doesn't need to call len, just `l2 = [item[0] for item in your_list if item]`

Comment: I am all for this list comprehension, def. a great idea

Comment: With a comprehension, you could even skip `your_list` and even `l2`: just `return [item[0] for item in reader if item]`

Comment: @johnColeman if you want to post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted. appreciate the feedback

Comment: @Quantico Maybe just accept the answer of Taegyung -- it looks like one of his first answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possibility I see is that there is an empty list in your_list.

Try:

```py
with open('path/AuthorNames.csv' ,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader) ## this generates [[auther1],[auther2],...]
    l2 = []
    for item in your_list:
        if item:
            l2.append(item[0])
```

or with list comprehension,

```py
l2 = [item[0] for item in your_list if item]
```

(Using list comprehension here is @John Coleman 's idea, just adding here for the completeness of this answer.)

And as I wrote in the comment, you may want to check your csv file to see if the empty line is a normal thing or if there's something wrong with your data there.

Comment: l2.append(item[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Quantico I'm sorry, a typo. It's `if item:`, not `if not item:`. By the way the error you see actually *means* there is an empty list in `your_list`, so you may want to check your .csv file to see if that's a normal occasion or if there's something wrong with your data in the file.